# Micronaut-data: Unable to resolve invalid query method [update] for simple example using Kotlin & MariaDB

Tags: kotlin, mariadb, micronaut, kapt, micronaut-data

[demo repo here](https://gitlab.com/dead_cat_bounce/micronaut-data-demo)

Trying to get past the following error in the most basic example case:

> Task :kaptKotlin FAILED
> error: Unable to implement Repository method: UserRepository.update(Object entity). Invalid query method [update] of repository [com.te.repositories.UserRepository]: No ID found for entity: com.te.model.User
> Note: Writing reflect-config.json file to destination: META-INF/native-image/com.te/model/reflect-config.jsonNote: Writing resource-config.json file to destination: META-INF/native-image/com.te/model/resource-config.jsonNote: Creating bean classes for 4 type elements
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':kaptKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Stubbed out the project at https://micronaut.io/launch/ and am trying to execute basic CRUD operations (after I get past this initial error that is...). Execution of `./gradlew clean build` yields the above error and I have been unable to resolve - help or insights appreciated - ty.

`application.yml`

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demo
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/test
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: passwd
    dialect: MYSQL
    poolName: muhPool
    maximumPoolSize: 50
    minimumIdle: 10
    isAutoCommit: false
    connectionTimeout: 250
    idleTimeout: 60000
    readOnly: false
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    maintainTimeStats: false
```

User table (mariaDB v10.3)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fname VARCHAR(50),
    lname VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(256)
);
INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('Pete','Jones','pete.jones@example.com');
INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('Paula','Jones','notabdule@example.com');
```

`User.kt`

```
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.GeneratedValue
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Id
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.MappedEntity

@MappedEntity(value="user")
data class User(@Id @GeneratedValue
                var id: Int,
                var fname: String,
                var lname: String,
                var email: String)
```

`UserRepository.kt`

```
import com.te.model.User
import io.micronaut.data.jdbc.annotation.JdbcRepository
import io.micronaut.data.model.query.builder.sql.Dialect
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository

@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.MYSQL)
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Int> {}
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
group = "com.te"

val kotlinVersion=project.properties.get("kotlinVersion")
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("spock2")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.te.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:mariadb")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:spock")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers")
    compileOnly("org.graalvm.nativeimage:svm")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.te.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per @graemerocher:

> See
> https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#kotlinData
>
> Id has to be @field:Id

Updated User.kt:

```
@MappedEntity(value="user")
data class User(@field:Id @GeneratedValue
            var id: Int,
            var fname: String,
            var lname: String,
            var email: String)
```